# WPF Control in small container size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have this problem. I need to know the size a Label is trying to use, but since the control that contains it is smaller than the actual label, when I call label.ActualWidth, what I really get is the width of said container control. Is there a way to get the width that the label would require to fit its content (disregarding its ACTUAL width)? Something like label.RequiredWidth, neither label.DesiredSize.Width or label.ActualWidth work.

Here's what I'm trying:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Width="100">
    <Label x:Name="aLabel">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
aLabel.ActualWidth; // this is 100 like the StackPanel
aLabel.DesiredSize.Width; // also 100 like the StackPanel
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
lb1.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
var requiredSize = lb1.DesiredSize;
```

Note, that this won't do any automatic text wrapping for you.

Comment: This is a lot simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to measure the length of the text, using Glyph widths. The following method accomplishes that:

```
public static double GetGlyphRunWidth(Typeface typeface, string text, int fontSize)
    {
        GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;
        if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
            return 0;

        ushort[] glyphIndexes = new ushort[text.Length];
        double[] advanceWidths = new double[text.Length];

        double totalWidth = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
        {
            ushort glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[n]];
            totalWidth += glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * fontSize;
        }

        return totalWidth;
    }
```

Comment: The size I get using this is extremely accurate to the real size of the label (adding label.Padding.Left and Right of course) Thanks!!

Comment: In addition to being more complicated than the accepted answer, this example will also fail to compute the size when the typeface in use is from a composite font (e.g. _"Global Monospace"_, _"Global Sans Serif"_, etc.)